# Data not saving correctly after upgrading Xcode 12.4 to 13.3.1

Tags: swift

I was working on an app using Xcode 12.4 and it was saving correctly. Now that I have got a new computer and upgraded to Xcode 13.3.1 when I enter "123456" it saves as "12345" if I enter "1234567" and then delete the "7" before saving it saves as "12345". If I enter "12345" or "1234567" and then hit save it works correctly.

I have no clue what part of the code could be causing this problem or what other information needs to be included.

I am thinking it is an Xcode problem and not a problem with my code.

I have a print statement on the save button and the code is wrong at that point. "123456" prints as "12345"

```
struct AddTripView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @StateObject private var addTripViewModel: AddTripViewModel
    
    init(repo: RepositoryProtocol) {
        _addTripViewModel = StateObject<AddTripViewModel>.init(wrappedValue: AddTripViewModel(repo: repo))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack {
                Text("BOL:").fontWeight(.bold)
                TextField("BOL", text: $addTripViewModel.bol).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    addTripViewModel.addTrip()
                    print("AddView \(addTripViewModel.bol)")
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class AddTripViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let repo: RepositoryProtocol
    @Published var saved: Bool = false
    
    var bol: String = ""
    
    init(repo: RepositoryProtocol) {
        self.repo = repo
    }
    
    func addTrip() {
        let trip = Trip(uid: "",
                        bol: bol)
        
        repo.addTrip(trip: trip) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let savedTrip):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.saved = savedTrip == nil ? false : true
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class FirebaseRepository: RepositoryProtocol {
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func getAllTrips(completion: @escaping (Result<[Trip]?, Error>) -> Void) {
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        db.collection("trips")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId!)
            .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
                    completion(.failure(error ?? NSError(domain: "snapshot is nil", code: 107, userInfo: nil)))
                    return
                }
                let trips: [Trip]? = snapshot.documents.compactMap { doc in
                    var trip = try? doc.data(as: Trip.self)
                    if trip != nil {
                        trip!.id = doc.documentID
                    }
                    return trip
                }
                completion(.success(trips))
            }
    }
    
    func addTrip(trip: Trip, completion: @escaping (Result<Trip?, Error>) -> Void) {
        do {
            var addedTrip = trip
            addedTrip.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            
            let reference = db.collection("trips").document()
            let uid = reference.documentID
            addedTrip.uid = uid
            try reference.setData(from: addedTrip)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to encode trip: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. If you are using SwiftUI start by watching "What's new in SwiftUI" from WWDC21 there were many changes with `TextField`. There is absolutely no way of helping you since we don't know anything about your project.

Comment: @loremipsum thank you for the reply I will check that out now. I figured it was something to do with the changes but had no clue where it could have been.

Comment: There are a few of the "What's new" videos like "What's new in Swift", "What's new in UIKit", Foundation, etc . They all offer good tidbits.

Comment: Inspect your code and track the way of the value you type starting from the input field all the way to the storage. Set breakpoints, check values at each point. If nothing helps and you're unable to build a minimal reproducible example, provide pieces of code that show how you get the value from the UI, how you process it, how it gets to the storage and it is read from the storage.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev thank you for that information.... I will try that after I finish this video. What has me so confused is it only has a problem saving 6 characters and only when I am on Xcode 13.3.1. I have no problem posting code but didn't want to post unnecessary information that wouldn't help find the problem.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev added some code... I have a print statement on the save button and the problem appears at that point

Comment: This may be irrelevant but your `addTrip` makes no sense: it takes a completion handler that it never calls.

Comment: @matt I will look into that thanks for pointing it out. I have had to add to and modify the function and must have missed that part.

Comment: You would do better to convert to async/await throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var bol: String = ""
```

To

```
@Published var bol: String = ""
```

Comment: That appears to work!!! Any idea why it was only an issue for 6 characters?

Comment: @OEZ no idea There is probably something deeper with the wrappers that we don't know about.

Comment: Okay... thank you for the help... at least I can keep progressing and hopefully improving at this point!